# firefox redirecting trailing slash

Tags: firefox, redirect

When I go to the url: `http://localhost/checkout/pay/393032-bb9320fc213459a-6c653c8bd1`
I get a 404 error, which is correct, because this page does not exist.

However, when I go to `http://localhost/checkout/pay/393032-bb9320fc213459a-6c653c8bd1/` (note the addition of a trailing slash) it redirects me to `http://localhost/pay/393032-bb9320fc213459a-6c653c8bd1` (without the /checkout), which also does not exist.

Why is the addition of a trailing slash causing it to redirect me? I don't have a .htaccess file, so it can't be that, and since the pages do not exist it can't be a script doing a redirect. When I look at the page in firebug, I don't see a redirect either, it seems to be changing the url invisibly, and I can't figure out why. Where should I look?

Edit: turns out it is only this one specific url that is being redirected, and it only happens in firefox, so I don't think it's an apache problem. I'm using Firefox 26.0, on ubuntu. what would make firefox pick one url and redirect it like this?

Answer (score 0):

See if you have Apache Module mod_dir activated

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

It will automatically add a / if needed and serve the default page.

Comment: I do, but I don't think that's it, because this is removing the "/checkout" folder from the path not just adding a slash